# Issue with join(str(x))

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, join

```
x = [1,2,3]  
print '-'.join(str(x))
```

Expected:

```
1-2-3
```

Actual:

```
(-1-,- -2-,- -3-)
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Because calling str on the list in its entirety gives the entire list as a string:

```
>>> str([1,2,3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

What you need to do is cast each item in the string to an `str`, then do the join:

```
>>> '-'.join([str(i) for i in x])
'1-2-3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You sent `x` to `str()` first, putting the given delimiter between each character of the string representation of that whole `list`. Don't do that. Send each individual item to `str()`.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> print '-'.join(map(str, x))
1-2-3
```